# Advanced @import styles for angular 8+

Tags: css, angular, import, sass, styles

I am using Angular 9. First look at my directory

```js
apps
.  -myapp
.       -src
.          -myscss.scss
libs
   -style
        -theme.scss
```

I want to import `theme.sccs` in `myscss.scss` style file.
I can do that with this

```css
/* mysccs.sccs */

@import "../../../libs/style/theme";
```

But I want to import like this

```css
/* myscss.scss */

@import "theme";
```

Can I get rid of `../../../`?How can I do that ?

Comment: you could modify  your project `tsconfig.json` file to end up with something like `@import @mylib/theme`, but I don't think you can get it shorten

Comment: @David I have successfully done to import `.ts` file by modifying `tsconfig.json` (setting up path). But this is working for `.ts` file only. I don't know will it be worked for style (css,sccs) file too. If it would be then please give me an example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong tsconfig is indeed for ts imports... I added an answer, see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`stylePreprocessorOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) in your `angular.json` file

**angular.json**

```
  "styles": [/* your project styles here */],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "../../libs/styles" /*correct path here*/
          ]
        }
```

Comment: Yes I got Error. 
`ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!../node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./styles.scss
Module build failed: 
@import "variables";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: variables.`